# In flutter code enableSlideIcon keyword not working

Tags: flutter

```
 return LiquidSwipe(
      pages: pages,
      fullTransitionValue: 350.0,
      enableLoop: false,
      **enableSlideIcon: true,**
      slideIconWidget: Icon(
        Icons.arrow_back_ios,
        color: dynamicColor,
      ),
    );
```

in the above the line enableSlideIcon give error.

[image]

Comment: share the error please , add screen shot or error code

Comment: 4thline of the code give error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
**enableSlideIcon: true,**
```

Use

```
enableSideReveal : true,
```